# Display user input from editText in listView usinng arrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview

I want my app to display the user input of editText in a listView. I have tried by using setText method but the problem is the required args are string and what I am passing is editText. So what could I do to pass the editText.

**MY mainActivity class**
        package com.example.manuj.autocalc;

```
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        EditText editTotal;
        EditText editItem;
        EditText editAmt;
        ListView listView;
        CustomAdapter customAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            editItem=findViewById(R.id.itemEdit);
            editTotal=findViewById(R.id.editTotal);
            editAmt=findViewById(R.id.amtEdit);

            final ArrayList<Calc> calcs=new ArrayList<>();
            listView=findViewById(R.id.listView);
            customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(this,-1,calcs);
            listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
            Calc calc=new Calc(editItem.getText().toString(),editAmt.getText().toString(),editTotal.getText().toString());
            calcs.add(calc);
            customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    }
```

**This is my Adapter class**

```
    package com.example.manuj.autocalc;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Calc> {
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Calc> calcs) {
            super(context, resource, calcs);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            Calc calc = getItem(position);

            if (view == null){
                view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }

            //get and set the items
            EditText item=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.itemEdit);
            item.setText(calc.getmItemEdit());

            //get and set the amt
            EditText amt=view.findViewById(R.id.amtEdit);
            amt.setText(calc.getmAmtEdit());

            //get and set the totalAmt
            EditText total=view.findViewById(R.id.editTotal);
            total.setText(calc.getmTotalEdt());

            return view;
        }
    }


    **This is my model class**
    package com.example.manuj.autocalc;


    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class Calc {
        private String mItemEdit;
        private String mTotalEdt;
        private String mAmtEdit;

        Calc(String itemEdit,String totalEdit,String amtEdit){
            this.mItemEdit=itemEdit;
            this.mTotalEdt=totalEdit;
            this.mAmtEdit=amtEdit;

        }


        public String getmItemEdit(){return mItemEdit;}

        public String getmTotalEdt(){return mTotalEdt;}

        public String getmAmtEdit(){return mAmtEdit;}
    }
```

Comment: Change your code up here, edit question, because this is a new problem, your old code doesn't give that error

Comment: Ok I found the problem,  it is because you put it in oncreate, where both your edittext got nothing, so when it run calc,  it give you the exception

Comment: One way to solve is to create a button, when user click that button then only you run Calc calc=new Calc(editItem.getText().toString(),editAmt.getText().toString(),editTotal.getText().toString()); calcs.add(calc); customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Okay i'll try.Thank you for your response.

Comment: No problem, I was once in your position, seeking for help, but no one willing to help, so I try to help people when I can

Comment: But what if i don't want to add a button?

Comment: Updated my answer but it just reference for you, because I'm using phone, can't really type much

Answer (score 2):

Your Calc class constructor needs 3 strings:

```
Calc calc=new Calc(editItem.getText().toString(),editTotal.getText().toString(),editAmt.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,But after updating the code still its causing a error,runtime error,the app is terminated and the reason is null object refenece at the editText.widget at line no 32 in MainActivity.java.which is the answer you updated.Calc calc=new Calc(....).Pleasee help me how to solve thiis.

Comment: I had a different order of total and amt in my answer, try if this was causing the problem.

Comment: Which is line no 32?

Comment: Calc calc=new Calc(editItem.getText().toString(),editTotal.getText().toString(),editAmt.getText().toString());  This is line no 32 in mainActivity.java and it causes a null order reference

Comment: Then check the 3 findviewbyid if they return null, maybe you misspelled their ids

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this

`(your edittext).getText().toString()`

as your argument to the `setText` intended.

You can also try to use textchangedlistener like this:

Sample code change yourself:

```
EditText searchTo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
searchTo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        doSomething();
    } 
});
```

Put your calc into onTextChanged but put at the last one of your edittext which take the user input, such as your app takes 2 input from user, which maybe edittext1 and edittext2,  put the textchangedlistener at edittext2, else it will return null exception again

Hope this helps!

Comment: Android studio is not allowing me to add the getText() method.What to do?

Comment: @Manuj Sharma what do you mean? Any code or screenshot of it?

Comment: But it's causing a null pointer exception due to getText().what to do?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.manuj.autocalc.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)

Comment: yes , Calc calc=new Calc(editItem.getText().toString(),editAmt.getText().toString(),editTotal.getText().toString());

Comment: @Manuj Sharma not here,  at your question there, so I can know what's the problem now

Comment: I've updated,Please have a look of my code and please help me

Comment: Hey,please help me regarding this,I'll explain in detail about this app.I want my app to  let the user enter a item and price and  will calculate the total.So  i made a layout of 3 ediText in a ListView,So that user can enter N numbers of details.But as you know i am facing null pointer exception in editText and i also used your updated sample code but still got null pointer exception.Please suggest me what could i do?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the adapter class

```
 package com.example.manuj.autocalc;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    import java.util.ArrayList;


    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Calc> {
        public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Calc> calcs) {
            super(context, resource, calcs);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

            Calc calc = getItem(position);

            if (view == null){
                view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                        R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            }

            //get and set the items
            EditText item=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.itemEdit);
            item.setText(calc.getmItemEdit().getText().toString());

            //get and set the amt
            EditText amt=view.findViewById(R.id.amtEdit);
            amt.setText(calc.getmAmtEdit().getText().toString());

            //get and set the totalAmt
            EditText total=view.findViewById(R.id.editTotal);
            total.setText(calc.getmTotalEdt().getText().toString());

            return view;
        }
    }


    **This is my model class**
    package com.example.manuj.autocalc;


    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class Calc {
        private String mItemEdit;
        private String mTotalEdt;
        private String mAmtEdit;

        Calc(String itemEdit,String totalEdit,String amtEdit){
            this.mItemEdit=itemEdit;
            this.mTotalEdt=totalEdit;
            this.mAmtEdit=amtEdit;

        }


        public String getmItemEdit(){return mItemEdit;}

        public String getmTotalEdt(){return mTotalEdt;}

        public String getmAmtEdit(){return mAmtEdit;}
    }
```